# Is it possible in an appwidget to detect a long press?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, long-press

I've figured out how to use setOnClickPendingIntent to detect and handle a press on a view, but I can't find any way to detect a long-press (or double-tap). I'd like to have different actions happen based on whether the user pressed or long-pressed. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, no, only ordinary taps are supported by `RemoteViews`.

Comment: then how [UCCW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.vineetsirohi.customwidget&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImluLnZpbmVldHNpcm9oaS5jdXN0b213aWRnZXQiXQ..) widget do?

Comment: @Tom you should accept this answer, it's accurate besides being a "no".

Comment: This makes sense when you think about it. Long pressing anywhere on a widget turns it into configuration mode.